Request for Guidance on Changing Default Admin Password for Commerce Module Installation
Changing Default Admin Password for Sitecore Commerce Module.
I want to change our default admin password for the Sitecore Commerce module. During installation, I noticed that the password is stored in the Global.json file for Authoring, Minions, Shops, and Ops app services.
I attempted to update the password in this file, but the admin account gets locked when trying to log in to BizFX. It only works with the default password used during installation.
Our security team is concerned about keeping the default password as it is known to many people.
Is it possible to read the password from Azure Vault?

From your description of the error, it looks like you may not have bootstrapped the Commerce services again after updating the passwords in the configuration files.
It is better to update the passwords and not use the default ones if your environment is publicly accessible.
Please check the following article which describes how to update admin password in Sitecore Experience Commerce:
https://www.jflh.ca/2018-09-24-update-the-sitecore-admin-password-when-using-sitecore-experience-commerce-9

thanks, it works

To change the defalut password of your commerce instance, use the following steps.

Stop application pool of the web applications installed with Sitecore commerce except (cm website).

Change the password mentioned in the Sitecore Commerce configuration files:


Here are the files.
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceAuthoring_Sc9\wwwroot\bootstrap\Global.json

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceAuthoring_Sc9\wwwroot\data\Environments\PlugIn.Content.PolicySet-1.0.0.json

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceMinions_Sc9\wwwroot\bootstrap\Global.json

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceMinions_Sc9\wwwroot\data\Environments\PlugIn.Content.PolicySet-1.0.0.json

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceOps_Sc9\wwwroot\bootstrap\Global.json

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceOps_Sc9\wwwroot\data\Environments\PlugIn.Content.PolicySet-1.0.0.json

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceShops_Sc9\wwwroot\bootstrap\Global.json
    
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceShops_Sc9\wwwroot\data\Environments\PlugIn.Content.PolicySet-1.0.0.json


Reset your IIS and open your websites.

You can unlock your account (If in case) using below SQL query:
UPDATE aspnet_Membership
SET
IsLockedOut = 0
WHERE UserId = (SELECT UserId FROM aspnet_Users WHERE UserName = ‘sitecore\Admin’)

Refer to this article for more details.
https://jitendrasitecore.wordpress.com/2018/12/13/change-default-password-sitecore-commerce/
Hope this helps.
